unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
i have this dockerfile :
FROM python:3.9-alpine AS base

ENV PYROOT /pyroot
ENV PYTHONUSERBASE ${PYROOT}
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${PYROOT}/bin

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile\* ./
RUN PIP_USER=1 pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile

FROM python:3.9-alpine

ENV PYROOT /pyroot
ENV PYTHONUSERBASE ${PYROOT}
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${PYROOT}/bin

RUN addgroup -S myapp && adduser -S -G myapp user -u 1234
COPY --chown=myapp:user --from=base ${PYROOT}/ {PYROOT}/

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=myapp:user app ./app
COPY --chown=myapp:user main.py ./
USER user

CMD \["uvicorn", "main:app","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"\]

when i run the following command:
$ sudo docker build -t myapp:latest . && sudo docker run --name testapp -p 8080 myapp:latest

i get this error :

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.


I realise it probably has nothing to do with this specific question, but I'd be really curious to know why the square brackets are escaped in the CMD statement.

That's not the only inappropriate escaping -- Pipfile\* is another example (I have trouble believing the file really has a * in its name, but that's what the backslash implies).

...that said, bigger issue, reading the Dockerfile, I don't see any command that's obviously expected to install uvicorn, unless that's the pipenv install. And if it is, we'd need to know where it's putting the binaries and how that compares to the PATH being set. And even assuming the binaries are being put in the right place and copied, the next step is to check whether the destination container has the shared libraries expected. All of these are checks that someone who actually has a container built from this Dockerfile can easily do, but where the result isn't obvious to read.

(if pipenv install downloaded eggs that contain shared objects built against glibc, f/e, it may well be that those libraries can't be loaded on Alpine; but that's pure speculation until someone looks in the container to see whether it has a uvicorn executable at the expected location and, if it does, whether ldd says that executable has its dependencies met).

Enter the command like this:
CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]. 

It helped me
